# Laravel sanctum getting wrong user

Tags: laravel, laravel-sanctum

I have logged user with my app and when I'm sending user token to get data from server its returning data of the wrong user.

**Debug**

1. I've debugged my app line by line from `login` to `stored token` in storage all showing correct token etc.
2. I've debugged my `API login function` line by line and it gets correct user and assign the token to it.

**Code**

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $user = $request->user();
        Log::info($user); // wrong user will be printed in log file
        $will = Will::where('user_id', $user->id)->with(['documents', 'videos', 'user'])->first();
        return response()->json([
            'data' => new WillResource($will),
            'message' => 'Data is ready.'
        ], 200);
    }
```

**Route**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:sanctum', 'prefix' => 'userdata'], function() {
   Route::get('mywill', 'Api\WillController@index');
});
```

**Any idea why sanctum returning wrong user data?**

## Update

Here is when I try it by postman

Login with user `postman@test.com`
[image: one]

Receive user info of `admin@admin.com`

[image: two]

Comment: It's the same with `Auth::user()`?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ yes it's same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solved**

The problem was that I am using `uuid` for my users table and `personal_access_tokens` table is morphable with `id` so I changed it to `uuidMorphs` and now it's working

```php
Schema::create('personal_access_tokens', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->bigIncrements('id');
  $table->uuidMorphs('tokenable'); // <--- here
  $table->string('name');
  $table->string('token', 64)->unique();
  $table->text('abilities')->nullable();
  $table->timestamp('last_used_at')->nullable();
  $table->timestamps();
});
```

Comment: This is a working solution, I have the same issue with UUID as the main ID of the users. Thanks!

Comment: I can confirm, that uuid was causing the problem and that this is a working solution

Answer (score 0):

```
 $token = $user->createToken($request->deviceName)->plainTextToken;
 $user['token'] = $token;
```

use approach like this create a associated token when user login /signup then add new key in $user['token'] and then return the response trough resource

Comment: still getting wrong results plus with `$token =` we are attaching token to user, having `$user['token']` does nothing.