# Laravel 8 Auth::user() or $request->user() return different or wrong user

Tags: php, authentication, authorization, backend, laravel-8

I got a bug, I think it's from laravel. Let says there is user1, user2, user3. When user1 and user2 login, the data is returned from that user using `$request->user()` and the data shows the correct users.

But when accessing another controller through different api then the data returned by `$request->user()` changes to different user. lets says it is user X (yes user X its only 1 user). When user3 login, all flow before works perfectly fine. Even using different controller still return the correct user. Here is my code.

Login function

```
public function login(LoginRequest $req)
    {
        $credentials = [
            'username' => $req->has('email') ? $req->email : $req->username,
            'password' => $req->password
        ];
        try {
            if (!Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
                return $this->sendError('The provided credentials do not match our records.', 400);
            }
            $user = $req->user();
            return $this->sendSuccess('Login successfully.', $this->authResponse($user));
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return $this->sendError($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

LoginRequest Validation

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required'
        ];
    }
```

Routes to get user

```
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum'])->group(function(){
Route::get('user', function (Request $request) {
        return $request->user();
    });
});
```

I tried changing different code with `Auth::user()` still it doesn't return the right user.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel sanctum getting wrong user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67899807/laravel-sanctum-getting-wrong-user)

Answer (score 0):

i just solved this issue using solution from this question : stackoverflow.com/a/67914315. im sorry if this is a duplicate question